# pmount hangs on BASH autocomplete

Tags: bash, debian, autocomplete

Whenever I try to use autocompletion in combination with `pmount` the terminal freezes until I abort via `CTRL+C` which leads to the autocompletion to actually be executed. Autocompletion works fine in any other respect and interestingly for unmounting `pumount` does directly and successfully autocomplete to any drives mounted via `pmount` independently of my working dir.

To be very clear a step-by-step process list:

```
#start pmount
pmount /de<TAB to autocomplete>
#terminal is frozen
<press CTRL+C once to unfreeze>
pmount /dev/s
pmount /dev/sd<TAB to autocomplete>
#frozen again - note the "d"
<press CTRL+C once to unfreeze>
pmount /dev/sdb
```

Note that in this case `/dev/sdb` is the only flash drive present, so the autocompletion is somewhat intelligent not to offer e.g. `/dev/sda`, but it still freezes.

I have tested a fresh, i.e. unconfigured install of `zsh` where autocompletion works fine with `pmount`, however does not behave as intelligently: at `pmount /dev/s<TAB>` the choice is not reduced to `/dev/sdb`, but also includes the "root hard drive" `/dev/sda` and `pumount <TAB>` autocompletes to entries of the current working directory.

So I assume that it is connected to the supposed intelligent autocompletion behaviour of BASH, but I cannot remotely solve the problem as I do not understand where this behaviour is even configured.

Any ideas how to solve the problem and where it even arises from?

System is Debian 8, `pmount` version is 0.9.23, `BASH` is 4.3.30

Comment: Bash intelligent autocompletes are stored in `/usr/share/bash-completions/completions`, on my system at least. If nothing else, you could move the file `pmount` in that directory elsewhere; that should disable the intelligent behavior and fall back on plain filename completion.

Comment: Thanks, I found such a file in `/etc/bash_completion.d/` and moving it does result in a fall back on simple completion as you predicted. I'll do my very best to find an error there to solve the problem and post it here - for the time being unintelligent behaviour it is.

Comment: I wrote [replacement completion functions](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/191141) (on Code Review) for `pmount` and `pumount`; it's also added to the [Debian bug report](//bugs.debian.org/776240) as a patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The autocomplete reference file is stored in `/etc/bash_completion.d/pmount` on my system.

**Solution 1 : (Re)moving/renaming the file**

As suggested by Tom Hunt, this is the simplest solution. The hanging stops, however the autocompletion is unintelligent, i.e. sticking to filenames of the current directory.

**Solution 2 : Repairing the autocompletion file**

The problem with the reference file arises in the function `_pmount()` at line 62 of the file (added newlines for readability - not in original file):

```
devices="$( command ls $(grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' /etc/pmount.allow )\
$(grep 1 /sys/block/*/removable |\
sed -e 's,/sys/block/,/dev/,;s,/removable:1,*,') 2>/dev/null |\
sort -u | sed -e 's,\(^/dev/\)\(.*\),\1\2 \2,' ; \
#this last line is of interest, as the errors occur here
grep $mdir /proc/mounts | sed -e 's,.*\($mdir/[^ ]*\).*,\1,' )"
```

with the error being that for

```
grep $mdir /proc/mounts
```

the variable `$mdir` is not defined previously and thus the script hangs.

So I added the definition of `mdir`

```
mdir="$(readlink -f /media)"
```

as taken from the `_pumount()` function of the same script (see line 75) at e.g. line 36 as `mdir` seems to be standing for **m**edia (or **m**ount) **dir**ectory, i.e. the standard mount point for `pmount`. Besides that I also added `mdir` to the local variables of the `_pmount()` function (line 25) for safety reasons.

Autocompletion now stops hanging, but if a removable drive's partition is mounted, it behaves oddly as it then shows the mounted drive, its mount point and all the information from `/proc/mounts`, e.g.:

```
/media/sdc1
rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0177,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,quiet,utf8,errors=remount-ro
```

This is due to the very same line 62, where the error occured, now the problem being this part:

```
grep $mdir /proc/mounts | sed -e 's,.*\($mdir/[^ ]*\).*,\1,'
```

where the `sed` command must fail (i.e. not work as intended, not fail as a command) as the single quotes suppress the evaluation of `$mdir`, thus I changed them to double quotes:

```
grep $mdir /proc/mounts | sed -e "s,.*\($mdir/[^ ]*\).*,\1,"
```

`pmount` autocompletion now skips information from `/proc/mounts`, but still shows already mounted partitions, including the `/media/sdc1` mount point.

I cannot tell which is the standard behaviour of `pmount`, but I did the following to actually suppress the listing of any partitions that have already been mounted, again initial line 62 is now changed to (added newlines for readability - should be removed in autocompletion script):

```
 devices="$( command ls $(grep -v '^[[:space:]]*#' /etc/pmount.allow )\
 $(grep 1 /sys/block/*/removable |\
 sed -e 's,/sys/block/,/dev/,;s,/removable:1,*,') 2>/dev/null |\
 sort -u | sed -e 's,\(^/dev/\)\(.*\),\1\2 \2,' \
 #previous block identical to original script
 #the following pipe replaces a semicolon from the original script
 #and so does anything that follows 
 | grep -v "$( if [[ $( grep $mdir /proc/mounts ) ]] ;
               then grep $mdir /proc/mounts |\
                    sed -e "s,.*\($mdir/[^ ]*\).*,\1," \
                        -e "s,$mdir/,," -e 's, ,\|,g' ;
               else echo $mdir ; fi \
             )"
 )"
```

Now in contrast to the original script, the first two `grep`s' output is piped to a `grep` where already mounted partitions are filtered versus any mounts in `/media` as taken from `/proc/mounts`. The `if` loop is needed to differentiate between the cases of an empty `/media` and one with already mounted partitions.

With these changes `pmount` will behave as below:

```
pmount <TAB to autocomplete>
/dev/sdc   /dev/sdc1  /dev/sdc2  /dev/sr0   sdc        sdc1       sdc       sr0
pmount sdc1
#successful mounting of sdc1
pmount <TAB to autocomplete>
/dev/sdc  /dev/sdc2  /dev/sr0  sdc       sdc2       sr0
```

I.e. the mounted partition is suppressed while other partition of the drive (and the drive itself) are still displayed.

Please note the importance of defining `mdir` as the first step!

**Side note on `pmount`**

Note that this autocompletion scans `/sys/block/*/removable` for `1`, i.e. only list devices where the removable bit is set. However other drives may be mounted by entering them via e.g. `pmount /dev/sdd1`, they just won't show up in the autocompletion. AFAIK this is intended behaviour and I'll keep it as it is. In my case this happens for an external hard drive where I have an `ext4` partition running.